# A bounded function which is the linear combination of its partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

If $f$ is a real-valued bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that for some $a, b$ in $\mathbb R$, $f(x, y)=a\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)+b\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)$ for all $(x, y)$. Does this mean that $f$ is identically zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be an arbitrary point in the plane and consider
$$ g(t) = f(x_0+at, y_0+bt) $$
Now compute $g'(t)$ by the chain rule. Together with your assumption that yields $g'(t) = g(t)$.